# typeof this for Generic Class with chaining methods in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Im tired of repeating Generic types over and over when writing generic class functions with chaining methods.

Take a look at the following code:

```js
class SomeGenericClass<TFoo, TBar, TBaz> {
  chainingMethod1(): SomeGenericClass<TFoo, TBar, TBaz> {
    // do something
    return this;
  }
  chainingMethod2(): SomeGenericClass<TFoo, TBar, TBaz> {
    // do something
    return this;
  }
}

// later
SomeGenericClass().chainingMethod1().chainingMethod2()
------
```

There's a lot of repeating ugly generic types in the above code.

```js
class SomeGenericClass<TFoo, TBar, TBaz> {
  chainingMethod1(): typeof this {
    // do something
    return this;
  }
  chainingMethod2(): typeof this {
    // do something
    return this;
  }
}
```

Is something like this possible with Typescript?

Comment: You don't need to declare a return type when you implicitly return `this`. You can also omit the `typeof` keyword.

Comment: @ShanevandenBogaard removing typeof worked! thanks! I am using all strict options so it bugs me if I don't add return type

Answer (score 1):

As @ShanevandenBogaard commented the following works!

```js
class SomeGenericClass<TFoo, TBar, TBaz> {
  chainingMethod1(): this {
    // do something
    return this;
  }
  chainingMethod2(): this {
    // do something
    return this;
  }
}
```